# How can I pass a server-side variable to HTML and have the HTML page return an auto-filled form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am building an HTML page in Google Apps Script with CRUD functionality. The user can currently add data, edit data, and search data (I am not adding a delete feature). I would like the user to receive the form url link with an ID that when they go BACK to that link, it auto-fills the form with the previously added data.

In my HTML file, I have the following button defined:

```
  document.getElementById("sbtn").addEventListener("click",getTID);
```

Once a user has entered data, it gets sent to a Google Sheet. The user HAS to enter a unique ID that they've already been provided. Using this ID, they can enter it, hit search, and it runs getTID():

```
function getTID() { //TID CODE
  var transID = document.getElementById("tid").value;
  if (transID.length === 36) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAllData).getID(transID);
  } else {
    alert("Transaction ID is not long enough.\nPlease copy the Transaction ID EXACTLY!\n\nFor Example: https:/workwebsiteconcealedforprivacy/w?txid=36275284-2ed6-4868-97b2-16bc1fde1a08\n\nThe Transaction ID is: 36275284-2ed6-4868-97b2-16bc1fde1a08")
  }
}
```

This takes the ID they gave, references the spreadsheet and then returns values it found by index. Now, I have in my server-side GS file, the following in doGet:

```
var urlValue = '';
function doGet(e) {
  // Test Code
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
  var list = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var htmlListArray = list.map(function (r) { return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var title = "Please Work";

  var vals = JSON.stringify(e);

  if ('v' in e.parameter){
    urlValue = String(e.parameter['v']);
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(urlValue);
  }

  return render("page",{list: htmlListArray, title});
```

and the following:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function render(file, argsObject) {
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
  if (argsObject) {
    var keys = Object.keys(argsObject);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
      tmp[key] = argsObject[key]
    });
  }
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

If I uncomment the return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(urlValue); line, I can see that IF an ID is in the URL, it returns the correct parameter.

My problem is that I cannot get the HTML to read the urlValue variable and autorun getTID() when the user enters the url with the correct parameter. The correct functionality is that IF the parameter is found, it auto populates the HTML form. If it doesn't, it returns the blank form.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question is hard do follow and looks that it requires more focus. Please spend some time searching this site for helfpul content and if you still needs help, please [edit] this question to make it more focused, add a [mcve], and a brief description of your search efforts including links to the most relevant posts.

Comment: @Rubén I've been looking at previous posts for over a week now. Most have the function attached to a button. I need the HTML page to autorun the search function and autopopulate the data based on the unique ID that passed as a parameter. I don't know how to simplify the question any further.

Comment: It looks that the first paragraph could be simplified. Instead of adding multiple large snippets of the client-side code add a minimal and complete client-side code. Only include a couple of input elements, the corresponding parent elements, one or two buttons and the minimal JavaScript required to handle them. NOTE the code doesn't show how the HtmlService.HtmlOutput object is created. Add a minimal and complete doGet function clearly showing how the HtmlService.HtmlOutput is created and returned. Add a brief description of the relevant parts of the source spreadsheet and add some sample data

Comment: @Rubén I just reformulated my question with the more relevant code. Like my question states: my search works, and my ability to capture the unique ID works. I just can't get the HTML page to auto-run a function with the urlValue variable.

Comment: The question still looks to require more focus as it has at least have one error, there are some decisions to be taken and the client-side code is uncomplete. I hope that my answer will help you get unstuck. There are already several questions about how to debug Google Apps Script projects including web apps, how to use scripts, and how to use google.script.url.getLocation. If you need further help please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error on

```
return render("page",{list: htmlListArray, title});
```

On `{list: htmlListArray, title}` the name of the second property is missing.

---

To "read the urlValue variable" there are two options:

- pass the parameters from the URL using the event object of the [doGet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) function. For this you have two options, create the HtmlService.HtmlOutput object from an html string generated using "vanilla" JavaScript or create it from a HtmlService.HtmlTemplate object.
- get the parameters from the URL directly on the client-side code using [google.script.url.getLocation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url) .

If you go for the first option, then you should pass someway the `urlValue` to the `render` function. In the question code `urlValue` is a global variable, so you might add the following before the `render`'s `return` statement.

```
tmp.urlValue = urlValue;
```

Then you have to add a scriptlet on the html file to handle this value and "autorun" `getTID`. Scriptlets is a feature of [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am new to using jS in GAS. I don't understand the error in the render function. I've added the tmp.urlValue = urlValue; inside the render function, since that makes sense to pass this to the client side. However, it *should* be an easy document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doStuffs); in my jS file where doStuffs just calls the search function. However, the page renders and ignores the parameter still. I will continue my search. Thanks again.

Comment: @Micah As I mentioned in the answer, you need to add a scriptlet. I added a link to the corresponding guide.

Comment: Sure, I'm just not sure that you've answered my question. Scriplets can't access my js file only the gs one. So, getting this to function from within the HTML file could be possible, but not working at the moment. The code to populate the fields is in js file while the code to get the values and store them as an array is in the gs file. So, the page probably is getting the data but not knowing how to display it.

Comment: No problem if you decide to not accept this answer, but please don't confuse "answering" a question with "meeting expectations". The focus of this site is provide answers to questions, not to meet all the expectations that new user might have. Since the question doesn't include a complete html I don't know if you are using scriptlets and in such case how you are using them. Anyway, please bear in mind that comments aren't intended to be used for discussions. If you have a follow-up question, please post it as a new question.